# Refering DBI functions in package - which to use?

Tags: r, r-package, r-dbi

When developing package using DBI extension (e.g. RJDBC, RSQLite) which package should I refer to?

```
connect_my_db <- function() DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my_db.sqlite")
```

or

```
connect_my_db <- function() RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "my_db.sqlite")
```

?

First method force me to use DBI in Imports, so I prefer second one. But on other side I should call virtual function and let R to decide what to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBI spec do require all backends to re-export all of DBI's methods, so both notations (`RSQLite::dbConnect()` vs. `DBI::dbConnect()`) are identical for all practical purposes:

```r
identical(DBI::dbConnect, RSQLite::dbConnect)
#> [1] TRUE
```

The `DBI::` notation expresses that you're using a DBI function, but if your package only uses `RSQLite` it seems fine to use that prefix from a code style point of view.

Answer (score 1):

From the viewpoint of the end-user, it doesn't matter: RSQLite depends on DBI, so your package will require both RSQLite and DBI to be installed anyway. From a stylistic viewpoint, I'd prefer the first approach, since otherwise you're second-guessing R's method dispatch mechanism.